# ClassCastException when subclassing ParseUser (Parse.com)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, subclass

I have some custom fields in my _User class on parse and I would like to subclass it in order to implement some convenience methods such as getName(), getSurname() and so on... usually i have no problems when subclassing ParseObjects, but with ParseUser I get a ClassCastException when obtaining the current user. Here is what I have done:

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
public class ParseStudent extends ParseUser { ... }
```

Then I subscribed the new class in my Application class

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseStudent.class);
```

When I try to access the current user as an instance of my subclass in this way

```
ParseStudent user = (ParseStudent) ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

I get the exception. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the custom subclass subscribing, which I performed after parse initialization. It must be done before it, as stated in the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-subclasses).